# can't load jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I reference to the library in the head section of my HTML page but I keep getting an error in my JS file when I type the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

});
```

The error is

> ERROR: $ is not defined. [no-undef]

I'm using Brackets

Full code of HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/CSS/style.css">
    <link rel ="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/CSS/sitegrid.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,300italic " rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.4.4/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel = "shortcut icon" type ="image/png" href="resources/images/favicon.ico">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/JS/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Add full code of your page

Comment: post your full code with your description everything suppose to be right but it isn't

Comment: Check the source url of jquery is correct or not.

Comment: Please add this jQuery library in head section and before your script:        
 http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: I've added code for HTML page

Comment: Use `jQuery` instead of `$` in `$(document).ready(function() {` like `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: what browser u r using? where did u write ur script? if the script loaded properly? have u check network console?

Comment: weird your code seems ok. Any other detail in your implementation?

Comment: _"[no-undef]"_ <- looks like an [es-lint rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef) and not a browser error. It's always important when asking a question like this to explain **where** you see the error

Comment: true @Henry are you using Eslint? I think Phil is up to something here

Comment: If you are you need to define jquery in the env object

Comment: Put: var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); at top of the resources/JS/scripts.js file